# Is it possible to use Powershell 7 as the debug console version in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I can't seem to find how to do this online, but essentially I am trying to debug a Powershell 7 script in VS Code, but whenever I launch the debugger it uses Powershell 5.1.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Cheers.

Comment: I hope the linked duplicate answers your question.

Comment: I was writing up an answer for this explaining how to change your default PS version for vscode and using the `Shell Launcher` extension... I learned something new (and feel dumb I never noticed) about the PS version badge at the bottom of the client. Never knew I could click it to change versions lol